# Yii2 ActiveQuery one column not equal another

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I need to select all records from DB where а column value is not equal to another one of the same row. In SQL, it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`created_at` != `logged_at`)
```

In Yii2, I try to do it like that:

```
$query = User::find()->where(['!=', 'created_at', 'logged_at']);
```

but it generates

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`created_at` != 'logged_at')
```

So, the question is, how can I use column name instead of string as the third param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [yii\db\Expression](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) class:

```
$query = User::find()->where(new yii\db\Expression('created_at != logged_at');
```